# How to run 2 sessions in a nested way in tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using tensorflow to train a network, which is the main session A. To preprocess the input data, I used spatial transformer network (tensorflow version). That basically means during training, the Session A starts first, and after each epoch, session B for preprocessing part of spatial transformer network will be used. In session B I have one line code like this

```
para = tf.Variable(initial_value=initial, name='para', trainable = False)
```

when I start to run, error occurs and indicate a RuntimeError

```
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

I am wondering what is the right way to solve this? To the best of my knowledge, there are two possible ways:
1) Merge the preprocessing part in the main Session A and use feed_dict to pass the parameters of preprocessing to the session.
2) find the way to handle the another session running for preprocessing during training of the main session A.

Do anyone has experience about this issue? Please help me.

Comment: New Info: one thing I just figure out is that I use tf.train.Supervisor so it will finalize the graph after runing sv = tf.train.Supervisor(...). The propocessing runs afterwards cannot modify the graph...

Comment: Yes, you are correct about using feed_dict to pass in parameters.  Another way is to use feed_dict to move your data into a **placeholder** and then use **tf.assign** to assign the value to a long lived variable.  The second option is useful if you are going to move in a large amount of data once and iterate over it lots of times.  It will save you the bandwidth of copying the data from RAM to the GPU on each iteration of induction.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving a large amount of data and it is different for each induction then you'll want to save the data once then continue with induction

```
# in the setup of your tensorflow graph
para_feed = tf.placeholder( dtype=tf.float32 , name='para', shape=[None,2] )
para = tf.Variable( dtype=tf.float32 , name='para', shape=[None,2] )
update_para = tf.assign(para,para_feed)

# to assign
sess.run( update_para , feed_dict={para_feed: initial})
# run your induction multiple times
# ...
```

If you do not have a large amount of data then simplify it like so

```
# in the setup of your tensorflow graph
para = tf.placeholder( dtype=tf.float32 , name='para', shape=[None,2] )

# run your induction multiple times 
sess.run( your_induction_target , feed_dict={para: initial})
```